# addImage function and Src

Tags: php, wordpress, phpword

I am creating a wordpress website that I would like to have the option of creating a MS Word file from each post with its metadata, but when I want to add a photo for specific post in the Word file, it gets this error:

> PHPWord/Section/Header.php on line 132

but I do not have this problem when the files of PHPWord are not used for Wordpress, I think the problem is addressing the path of each post's photo that I am using the following line to do that:

```
$photo_generale_address = get_template_directory_uri() . "/files/$post_year/$post_month/$post_day/$post->post_name/Photo Générale.jpg";
```

Any recommendation? why it is happenning and how could I fix it?

Comment: I think you're missing the first part of that error. It should say what happened on line 132. Can you post the rest plz?

Comment: You're sure that path is valid? Could you do some `var_dump` of `$photo_generale_address` to see? And maybe give it a try with a non-accentuated file name - maybe PHPWord doesn't support that well.

Comment: this is the full warning:
Warning: Invalid error type specified in /Applications/AMPPS/www/wordpress/wp-content/themes/MyRapport/PHPWord/Section/Header.php on line 132
The path works well for other things like QRCode and images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fix it using adding an absolute path for the photos, PHPWord just accepts absolute path of files:

```
$template_uri = dirname(__FILE__);
echo $template_uri;
$header = $section->createHeader();
$LogoFirstPage = array('width'=>250, 'height'=>51, 'align'=>'left');
$header->addImage($template_uri.'/logo.png', $LogoFirstPage);
```

It is solved now, Thanks from everyone who answered or commented my question.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this to pass the image

```
if(has_post_thumbnail()) { 

$image=the_post_thumbnail();         
$photo_generale_address=$image;

}
```

Comment: The photos are not the thumbnail(s) of the post, I am making a bigdata storage by wordpress, so I have manipulated many things.
I have a photos to use them for header of the word file I desire to make from the posts, the photos are working when the PHPWord library is used in another directory of server, but when I use the library in the directory of wordpress template it does not work. It is the problem of PHPWord library.
I also checked the file which is taking the error "header.php" line 132, but there is no logical problem that I could modify it to fix the problem.